# XAML UWP Textblock center alignment issue

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to align the text block center but the text is left aligned.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="22" Width="192" />
```

Please help to align center. The code block is as follows

```
 <ListView x:Name="listview" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection}" 
                  GotFocus="StackPanel_GotFocus" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" Margin="144,360,45,0" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}">

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="130" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="130" Width="200" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="108" Width="192" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="22" Width="192" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using TextBlock.TextAlignment?

Comment: Thanks it works well.

Comment: Or just leave the Width out of the textblock element.  You're setting the width and it's centered but the text within it isn't.  Prior suggestion works also, just a heads up.